# Higher resolution maps and a higher zoom level

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With the Google Maps API, the highest resolution/zoom level I can get for an address is two levels less than what I can get on maps.google.com.

For example, using the address: Red's Java House, Pier 30, San Francisco, CA

With the API I get (at zoom level 20 - max zoom):

[image]

And then on maps.google.com I get (at zoom level 22 - max zoom before street view):

[image]

I've contacted Google sales, which, at least at the level I'm at, is run through a third party company.  They say the higher resolution should be available now.  With the new Google Maps Platform that was released on June 11 of this year, you should be able to just signup on the website and get the increased resolution images along with everything else.  This does not appear to be the case.

I can't find any reference to higher resolution images and greater zoom levels on the Google Maps Platform website.  Does anyone know what it takes to get higher resolution images via the Google Maps API?

### Update June 16

As @MrUpsidown points out in his comment below, the API and maps.google.com are different products, hence the different max zoom levels.  I had a discussion with a Google Maps sales rep and he set me straight.

Comment: You could try updating your google maps package to the most current version, and generate a new key (if you aren't paying for a key). If those don't work, it sounds like you are at the mercy of google's api and customer support.

Comment: @rhavelka Thank you for responding.  I've tried those approaches, but to no avail.  I do feel at their mercy (crickets chirping).  I also wouldn't normally ask a question like this on Stack Overflow.  It's already received one down vote, because...  But, Google wants you to use SO for support.  I get where they are coming from, but this is a little painful.  And it seems like such a simple question they could answer on their website.  Oh, well.  I may need to checkout Mapbox as an alternative.

Comment: I know google maps caches images but they should be released on every page reload. I just checked my implementation of google maps and it seems to be high resolution. what language, google maps package version, and google maps api libraries are you using?

Comment: @rhavelka thanks for following up.  I'm using the Maps JavaScript API v3.3.  I also tried v3.exp.  And, I'm using the places and drawing libraries.  With your implementation of Google Maps, are you able to get a similar resolution/zoom level to what's available on maps.google.com?

Comment: I guess I am using the `@types/googlemaps` package in angular5, but it references the same google api. I am using the visualization and places libraries but adding/removing them doesn't really change much. I do get similar resolution to what is on maps.google.com and mine even does a 3d view when you zoom in far enough. Maybe try to delete and reinstall any dependencies that you have, and clear any caches. That's about all I got for you.

Comment: @rhavelka Interesting.  I'll checkout the angular 5 package and see I can find any differences between how I'm doing things and how they're doing it.  Thanks for taking a crack at helping me out.  I appreciate your time.  Cheers.

Comment: Where is the information that Google will upgrade zoom level or image quality in their API starting June 11? Google Maps and Google Maps API are 2 different products and there is **absolutely no guarantee** that you will get the same tiles, same images, same quality you see on Google Maps website, with the API. @rhavelka's comments are wrong. You might get high quality images through the API in certain areas, not in others. But I have never seen the API let you zoom in as much as their website does and the rendering engine seems totally different anyway (3d).

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for the response.  One of the benefits listed on the old premium account pricing page was getting higher resolution imagery.  I assumed this meant they were giving higher resolution/zoom similar to maps.google.com (2 zoom levels greater than the free account) to people who paid.  When I swapped out my free account API key for a new Platform API key the resolution available to me didn't change, which I found confusing.  At this point, I think the higher resolution referenced on the old pricing page had already been made a part of the free API key at some point.

Comment: @MrUpsidown And, yes, you're correct that they are different products.  I **had** assumed they were the same.  I had a discussion with a Google Maps sales person and he explained that they were different, hence the different resolutions.  Perhaps I should have seen that.